# SQL Server: CASE ignoring rows with NULL values within SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am experiencing an interesting problem with a NULL value in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.STAFF (
staffID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
lastname varchar(50) NULL,
firstname varchar(50) NULL,
pay money NULL,
supervisorID int NULL 
)

INSERT INTO STAFF (staffID, lastname, firstname, pay, supervisorID)
VALUES  (1, 'Smith', 'John', 60000, NULL),
    (2,'Jones', 'Bridget', 13000, 1),
    (3,'Robinson', 'Smokey', 14000, 1),
    (4, 'Vedder', 'Eddie', 13000, 3),
    (5, 'Almighty', 'Bruce', 12000, 2),
    (6, 'Addington', 'Jane', 11000, 2),
    (7, 'Hogan', 'Hulk', 10000, 3),
    (8, 'Jackson', 'Jacky', 15000, 2),
    (9, 'Samuelson', 'Sammy', 14400, 1)
    ;
```

When I run this query the first row isnt returned and it seems it is being ignored because of the null value. Why does this not work. I assume it is something to do with the NULL value in  a CASE statement within a self-join? I am really interested as to why this wont work.

```
SELECT (a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname) AS "Employee Name",
CASE 
WHEN a.supervisorID IS NOT NULL THEN (b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastname)
ELSE 'No supervisor'
END AS "supervisor Name"

FROM dbo.STAFF a, dbo.STAFF b
WHERE a supervisorID= b.staffID;
```

[image: query ouput]

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with a `CASE`? The case just computes a value, it never removes rows. Easy to confirm by deleting the `CASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a LEFT JOIN. I think if join type isn't give INNER JOIN is default.

Comment: If you use the `JOIN` keyword by itself, you're right, you'll perform an `INNER JOIN`. The OP, however, is using `,`, which is a `CROSS JOIN`, and then filters in the `WHERE` clause. The effect is exactly as if the OP had used an `INNER JOIN`, but without actually using that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT (a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname) AS "Employee Name",
CASE 
WHEN a.supervisorID IS NOT NULL THEN (b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastname)
ELSE 'No supervisor'
END AS "supervisor Name"

FROM dbo.STAFF a
LEFT JOIN dbo.STAFF b
WHERE a supervisorID= b.staffID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, slight changes to the query and it works just fine :)

```
SELECT (a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname) AS "Employee Name",
CASE 
WHEN a.supervisorID IS NOT NULL THEN (b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastname)
ELSE 'No supervisor'
END AS "supervisor Name"
FROM dbo.STAFF a
LEFT JOIN dbo.STAFF b
ON a.supervisorID = b.staffID;
```